# Form always visible even when radiobutton value is changed (form api)

Tags: 7, javascript

i'm having an issue with the property #states visible on a form.

I want to hide it when form mercuriale's value is 1.

```
$isMercuriale = db_query('SELECT isMercuriale FROM groupes_catalogues WHERE id = ' . $idCatalogue)->fetchField();

  $form['mercuriale'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Type de catalogue'),
    '#default_value' => $isMercuriale,
    '#options' => array(
      '0' => t('Classique'), 
      '1' => t('Mercuriale'),
    ),
  );

  /* Secteurs */
  $listeSecteurs = db_query('SELECT tid, name AS nom FROM taxonomy_term_data WHERE vid = 7 ORDER BY nom');
  $header = array(
    'nom' => t('Secteur'),
    //'reduc' => t('Réduction (%)'),
    //'option' => t('Statut'),
  );

  $options = array();
  foreach($listeSecteurs as $secteur)
  {
    $options[$secteur->tid] = createFieldsCatalogue('secteurs', $secteur->tid, $secteur->nom, $idCatalogue);
  }
  $form['secteurs'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => $uid,
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="mercuriale"]' => array('value' => 0),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

What am I missing ?
Thank you.

Comment: Since a tableselect is expanded into more than one element, you wouldn't expect anything to happen when you attach states to it (if it did, the result would be ambiguous at best). You'll probably need to hook into the `#after_build` for the element and make changes to the individual elements that way

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I do not understand how i could make this work with the #after_build.
It only allows to call a custom function ... ?